# Cannot start ReactNativeProject

Tags: react-native, npm-install

I followed the tutorial in the link here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content . As it turns out, npm 5 is not supported yet. I tried installing npm 4 but, it is not working either. Stuck in the first page of the tutorial, when I run npm start, I am getting a bunch of errors too. Literally stuck, nowhere else to turn. Before voting down the question, kindly note that I am a mobile developer working with andorid and Ios having no previous knowledge about web technologies. Thanks

These are the steps I followed

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

It was successfull, then,

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
```

for this line, I got the following error

```
    *******************************************************************************
ERROR: npm 5 is not supported yet
*******************************************************************************

It looks like you're using npm 5 which was recently released.

Create React Native App doesn't work with npm 5 yet, unfortunately. We
recommend using npm 4 or yarn until some bugs are resolved.

You can follow the known issues with npm 5 at:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16991

*******************************************************************************
```

Then I ran the command

```
cd AwesomeProject
```

Afterwards I ran

```
npm start
```

for which I got the error

```
    npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jayakrishnan/.npm/_logs/2017-07-25T08_13_06_277Z-debug.log
```

I tried using Yarn But didnt work

Comment: show your error which you got.

Comment: same problem for me too..but solved by below code @Balasubramanian

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`npm i -g npm@4.6.1` - then install `create-react-native-app` again and create a project.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this worked for me.. Can you please edit the answer explaining what the command does.. Thank you once again

Comment: `npm i -g` means install 4.6.1 version globally. Further info [click here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16991)

Answer (score 2):

Solution with **Yarn**:

First install Yarn

```
yarn global add create-react-native-app
cd AwesomeProject
yarn start
```

Answer (score 1):

npm install -g npm@4 Use this to downgrade, Also use sudo with the commands, sometime it does give permission to write error and skips the installation

Answer (score 0):

Try putting more information about the error so we can help, or steps to reproduce it.

One thing to try is to instead of using `npm`, use `yarn`. Install `yarn` with `brew install yarn` if you are on mac and do the same steps in the `getting-started` guide, except for use `yarn run ios` to start app in ios simulator.
I just tried with a fresh setup that this is working perfectly fine.

Reference to `yarn` https://yarnpkg.com/en/